# Weird Box-Collider Bug in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since today I have a very strange bug in Unity 2018.3.7f1 (my company currently only supports the 2018 version). As soon as I switch on any box collider I only have <10 FPS, if I switch the box collider off again I immediately have >80 FPS again. According to Unity Profiler, the problem is physics.
Here is an example with a scene with only a cube… once with the box collider switched on and once with the box collider switched off.
Anyone have an idea what the problem could be? The problem also occurs with a new project.

[Cube with BoxCollider Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUCov.png)

[Cube with BoxCollider On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO8St.png)

Comment: GPU driver update maybe?

Comment: Could you click on the big orange blob the in the profiler and post the CPU usage breakdown? (The "Main Thread" section in the timeline in the profiler)

Comment: Does this happen even if there is no rigidbody on your object?

Answer (score 0):

@YGreater Yes, it's completely independent of Rigidbody.

@ipodtouch0218 "Physics.Processing / 0.085ms / Total: 83.13ms (997 Instances)" The many instances are very strange. I think I was able to narrow down the problem, I think the origin of the problem could be that I used my own AssetBundle before and something has been causing problems there recently (this AssetBundle actually always worked in the past). It's funny that I only have it in the project hierarchy at the moment, but don't load it in the scene. To be on the safe side, here is the code I basically use for the project:

```
private void Awake()
{
    if (File.Exists(Helper.mlFilePath))
    {
        MLFile file = JsonUtility.FromJson<MLFile>(File.ReadAllText(Helper.mlFilePath));

        var loadedAssetBundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromFile(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/simulation_bundle"));

        if (loadedAssetBundle == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Failed to load AssetBundle!");
            return;
        }

        foreach (var obj in file.Objects)
        {
            foreach (var gameObject in loadedAssetBundle.LoadAllAssets<GameObject>())
            {
                if (gameObject.GetComponent<MetaData>().getVisualId().Equals(obj.Symbol.VisualId))
                {
                    float yOffset = 0;
                    if (gameObject.name.Contains("WT"))
                        yOffset = 0.25f;

                    Instantiate(gameObject, new Vector3(obj.Position.X / 100, yOffset, obj.Position.Y / 100), Quaternion.Euler(0, obj.Rotation, 0));
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        loadedAssetBundle.Unload(false);
    }

    this.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime;

    Time.timeScale = 1f;
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can respond to a comment in your question - instead of adding `@` in the body of the question. I think this entry is an edit to your question. For edit your question, press the [edit] link under your question.